# CSS Not properly Working in localhost

Tags: css, wordpress, localserver

I’m using localhost for wordpress theme development by xampp server. When I change in my css file it not work instantly. Its work  may be after  3-4 hours.    css dynamically linking is ok.  Wht’s the problem plz.?

Comment: Explain your problem by putting some code here!

Comment: How you are calling css? please share code

Comment: I call css file with PHP code directly from root

Comment: Please share code by update your question.

Comment: I have use this code <?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>

Comment: linking or calling file is may be is not problem. Its has problem may be others because after 3-4 hours CSS change wordk.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes I have found that the browser will cache assets when running under localhost and make it appear as though updates are not taking effect. It's hard to tell from your description if this might be the problem, but try clearing cached images and files and see if that helps.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you have some intense caching. In local development you can bust the cache with a different version numbers in your `wp_enqueue_style` call. Version number is the 4th parameter. In this example, we'll update the version number to be the current date/time of the latest change to the `style.css` file.

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {
    $cacheBusterCSS = date("U", filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), $cacheBusterCSS );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

This kind of dynamic version number is **only** for local development and is a bad idea for production sites when you *want* to leverage caching for better page load times.